# User-friendly API with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I am implementing a simple GUI for OpenGL, mostly as an exercise for myself. The idea is to have a Gui class, where each instance can be assigned to a different render target (e.g. back buffer or texture). GUI elements (widgets) are assigned to exactly one instance of the Gui class. I suppose storing elements inside a GUI is a typical use case for [unique_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/). Here is what I came up with:

```cpp
class Element {
public:
    Element();
    virtual ~Element();

    static std::unique_ptr<Element> create_unique();
};

class Gui {
public:    
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Element> element_ptr;    
    Gui();
    void addElement( element_ptr element );
    void addElementRaw( Element* element );

private:
    std::list<element_ptr> elements;
};

int main(void) {
    Gui gui;

    gui.addElementRaw( new Element() ); // 1

    gui.addElement( Element::create_unique() );  // 2

    gui.addElement( std::unique_ptr<Element>(new Element()) ); // 3

    auto el = Element::create_unique();
    gui.addElement( std::move(el) ); // 4
}
```

I don't want a potential user of the GUI have worrying about moving the pointer around. However, I want to make it clear from the API that the GUI class takes ownership of the Element.

1. Passing a raw pointer: Simple usage, but the API does not make it clear that ownership was passed.
2. factory function: Simple usage, but the function needs to be re-implemented for each class derived from Element.
3. Manually creating a unique_ptr: cumbersome for the user
4. Move semantic: seems cumbersome too.

I am not happy with my solution(s). What I want is the simplicity of (1) while making it clear from the API that the gui now owns the element.

Comment: #3 will be simplified with `std::make_unique` in C++1y.

Comment: True, but the user would still need to bother with the fact that there is a unique_ptr involved... however, after all that might be desirable.

Comment: I would suggest a quick read over [this GOTW](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about just providing the arguments for the new element?

```
template< typename... T >
void addElement( T&&... t )
{
    elements.emplace_back( std::unique_ptr< Element >( new Element( std::forward< T >( t )... ) ) );
}
```

With C++14, you could also use `std::make_unique`:

```
template< typename... T >
void addElement( T&&... t )
{
    elements.emplace_back( std::make_unique< Element >( std::forward< T >( t )... ) );
}
```

In case you want to create elements derived from `Element`, you could also do this (C++14 version):

```
template< typename C, typename... T >
void emplace_back( T&&... t )
{
    elements.emplace_back( std::make_unique< C >( std::forward< T >( t )... ) );
}
```

and it can be used like this:

```
gui.emplace_back< Element >();

// insert a class derived from Element (hope you have a virtual dtor!)
gui.emplace_back< DerivedFromElement >();

// calls Element::Element( int, const char* ) or similar...
gui.emplace_back< Element >( 42, "Hallo" );
```

Comment: +1 But I'd call this one `emplaceElement` and leave the existing `addElement` as is (and rename `addElementRaw` to `addElement`)

Comment: @Praetorian While writing the answer I called it `emplaceElement` initially, so yeah, this seems like a good idea. But OTOH it might be confusing as it inserts a `unique_ptr` and not the raw `element`, so I'll leave it to the OP to decide what is most appropriate for his use-case. After all, the API should not reflect the implementation details, but communicate the semantics.

Comment: Could this possibly leak? I mean, `emplace_back` needs to allocate first, then in-place construct the new element from the arguments. If the allocation fails, the argument is just a raw pointer and might get leaked. Correct?

Comment: @DyP Good catch! Yes, it could potentially leak, I fixed the answer.

Comment: That seems perfectly what I was looking for. Unfortunately I don't understand how it works. When doing gui.addElement(Element()); the constructor is called once, but the destructor is called twice..

Comment: @kazemakase Because you created an unnecessary temporary that is constructed, copied (into another `Element` managed by the `unique_ptr`) and destroyed. Try: `gui.addElement();` - don't provide the element, just the *arguments* to create an element (they are forwarded to the ctors of class `Element`).

Comment: @kazemakase: you have to call this way `gui.addElement();`

Comment: How does this work with classes derived from Element?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `elements.emplace_back(new Element( std::forward< T >( t )... ) );` ?

Comment: @kazemakase Instead of hardcode `Element` add another template parameter for the type, so the call will look like `add<Element>([arguments...]);`

Comment: @kazemakase Edited the answer for derived classes.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo No, that's the memory leak DyP found.

Comment: Given that this is a GUI framework, it's reasonably likely that the client will want to do some additional setup on the new element. I would return a reference from `addElement`.